# Are exported environment variables in GitHub actions available across all steps?

Tags: github-actions

Is `VAR_X` still available at the step Y or do I have to export it at each step where I need it available?

```yaml
steps:
- name: X
  env:
    VAR_X: ${{ inputs.var_x}}
  run: |
    export VAR_X=$VAR_X

- name: Y
  env:
    VAR_X: ${{ inputs.var_x}}
  run: |
    export VAR_X=$VAR_X
```

Comment: See [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) (workflow level) versus [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv) (job level) versus [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv) (step level).

Comment: Regarding `export`, each [`run` represents a different shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) so it won't be accessible to other `run` sections. If you want to set env var to use in subsequent steps, see [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `inputs`, looks like you can simply avoid `export` and may directly be able to use  [`env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) (workflow level) or [`jobs.<job_id>.env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv) (job level) or [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv) (step level) according to your use case.

Regarding `export`, each [`run` represents a different shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) so it won't be accessible to other `run` sections. If you want to set an environment variable from a `run` section to use in subsequent steps in the same job, see [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) for more details.